# transfer to UEFI boot with ubuntu bootrepair is giving an unbootable system - WARNING possibly incompatible MBR signature

Tags: boot, uefi

Transfer to UEFI boot with ubuntu bootrepair is giving an unbootable system - the cause is perhaps a risky MBR signature FF00 instead of FE00 set by "boot-repair" and eventually also by ubuntu (MATE 22.10) install - I got a warning possibly incompatible MBR signature ff.

How to repair this problem - or at least to check, if it's is really the cause?

Details:
(my system: AMD ryzen 1700x with Gigabyte GA-AB350-GAMING Firmware 31 - CSM or only UEFI boot. formerly MBR boot starting only linux systems on 4 TB hd0 and nvme-disk. GPT on disc since beginning, newly converted to GPT on nvme disc )

Using boot-repair I transferred to UEFI.
Boot repair was setting for UEFI boot on NVME disc, but NVME disc is promptly vanished from boot menu - no method to correct that with boot firmware.
Fresh UEFI install on nvme didn't change things.

I installed ubuntu MATE 22.10 with UEFI on the other disc with boot from that disc (which was up to this time was prepared for MBR boot).
After "successful install" no boot at all is possible - there is no remaining bootable disc.

Check with life system (gparted, ..) was giving a warning (MBR signature FF, which may eventually prevent boot depending on boot firmware). UEFI compatible MBR signature should be EF00).

Now I'm only able to boot life systems and boot the new system from the BOOT> console, for all other systems I found no boot possibility.
After booting from boot console,
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y boot-repair && boot-repair

were working, but without visible effect

Comment: Post link to report (not report) from Boot-Repair in question above, as it suggests, so we know your details. Does gdisk give any fixes? http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html
More repair info  use p, v & w to write the partition table. If not correct just use q to quit. :
http://askubuntu.com/questions/386752/fixing-corrupt-backup-gpt-table/386802#386802

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bFNJv4WGvf/

Comment: in fact I run boot-repair often without success, at last some times "success", this wasn't the last time. gdisk v  wasn't finding any error, up to now I didn't use gdisk p.

Comment: You show 4 installs, but only one UEFI boot entry. And of the two Ubuntu entries one does not look valid. Only line 35 boot 0001 should work, but Ubuntu entry 0000 will not. Do you get grub menu? You may need to boot recovery mode? What video card/chip? You also have BIOS version of grub installed in various places. Almost never should be installed to a partition. You also have BIOS version in NVMe drive. And syslinux (Windows type boot loader in other partitions. If correctly installed, you have to boot  a drive in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. But since UEFI, you should only be booting in UEFI mode.

Comment: Are some drives removable? UEFI forgets UEFI boot entries for removable drives. I would make sure main working install is totally installed only on fast NVMe drive. You would then need an ESP - efi system partition on the NVMe drive and reinstall grub for all installs you want UEFI boot into that ESP. Note that Mint & Ubuntu use ubuntu entry in UEFI even though Mint not an official Ubuntu distribution. Last install or update of grub will then be default boot.

Comment: I've no proof, that my early rizen is booting from NVME disc. Just now I tested:
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo gdisk /dev/sda
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.8

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.Up to now I've used boot block from SDA. An actual check using live disc: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo gdisk /dev/sda
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.8

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present
Verify ok, ...

Comment: to oldfred: all correct. my main system is mint on  nvme, 2 backup systems because of former sys instabilities. 2017 I started with UEFI on sda - too much troubles. Removable drive: yes, was a try to establish UEFI boot without damaging working system.The "protective MBR" together with the BIOS seems to be the real problems - UEFI spec is awaitng 'FE00' type in MBR, 'FFxx'  says "disk not bootable", which is only mostly(!) interpreted as "disk without MBR boot". UEFI boot was before win11 in compatibility mode, and working on my PC. "Correct" EFI partitions are installed on SDA and NVME

Comment: Protective MBR, is really there to show old partition MBR only tools that drive is partitioned as gpt. But can be used for old BIOS boot with bios_grub partition. But for UEFI systems better to boot in UEFI mode. Do not know Mint other than similar, but not identical to Ubuntu, nor official flavor. Use Boot-Repair's advanced mode, and choose install & NVMe drive for boot loader.

Comment: Done. (CSM deactivated. started: UEFI:USB drive ... (live ubuntu 22.10)
boot repair giving:Während der Reparatur ist ein Fehler aufgetreten.
--no-nvram exit code: 1 Bitte melden Sie diese Nachricht an boot.repair@gmail.com

Bitte auf ein Papier die folgende Adresse notieren:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MhhVqjMsPd/

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip? Double check the nvme0n1p1 is FAT32 with boot,esp flags. You may need to repair it also with dosfsck. Use Boot-Repair's advanced mode and also choose to install latest kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the solution: UEFI boot from hard disc (perhaps no boot over NVME possible).
Last steps: destroy UEFI MBR entries written by boot repair stick ('BST') in MBR mode. Change boot order to sda. Reboot with BST in UEFI mode, repair boot entry ("success" - but no reboot (no internal and no life system bootable). Now to boot mate from konsole ( UEFI mode, boot> prompt ) was working.
Boot repair from mate install medium was saying "success", protocol looking good.
New start - could set no start device. Accepted. Next system start: full boot menu, all 3 UEFI systems (on sda and nvme).

Fazit: Much too much work, just for fun. Would have been much simpler to erase all.
Your help: 1 user marginally, others minus infinity. Much thanks.
I'll quit here. This forum has proven as the worst I've seen in the last 40 years.
If you have an 2017 ryzen with GA-AB350-GAMING motherboard running under classic boot, you shouldn't think to try to set it up for UEFI with ubuntu boot repair or you may earn a nightmare. Save all data, erase all, start from a clear system.